# Expand tableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my app I have a UITableView, its cells contains a text with different content, and UIButton.

When the user clicked on the cell button, the cell should expand to show all the cell's text content. so the height of the expanded cell will be different depends on the text content.

I searched a lot about this problem, but no useful results :S .

I tried this way, but it doesn't give me the right content, some times the cell expanded right, sometimes not,

```
   let fixedWidth = tmpCell.textView.frame.size.width
        tmpCell.textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))//CGFloat.max
        let newSize = tmpCell.textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
        var newFrame = tmpCell.textView.frame
        newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
        tmpCell.textView.frame = newFrame
        self.heightForTextView = tmpCell.textView.frame.size.height

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
```

any one nows how to implement this issue?
or what's the wrong in my way?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your way is fine. (Though I haven't fully read through it)
You will have to set a new frame for your cell in order to enlarge it and you will have to layout the cell's content accordingly. Doing this programmatically is ok.

However, you will have to tell the table how big your cells are. Usually this is a property on the table `UITableView.rowHeight`. But that is suitable only when all cells have the same hight which does not suit your needs.

In your case you will have to respond to calls to `tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)` returing the correct height for each cell.

So when the user touches the button then you do not directly change the appearance of your cell. You rather store somehow the new stat of the object displayed in that cell. Introduce some boolean extended property or so. Then call UITableView.reloadData() on your table to make it redraw itself upon the changed data. Then respond to it as if you were drawing the cells for the first time. Evaluate the extended property (or whatever you use to store the state of the cells) and layout it accordingly. You can do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPat` or you can do this in a subclass of UITableCellView, that you may use already. However, it's not a bad idea subclassing UITableViewCell for these pruposes.